# "Unknown error" in my Chrome extension

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am writing (or attempting to write) my first Chrome extension, and I cannot figure out this error I keep getting. My background code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script>

    console.log('works?');

    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code:"document.body.style.fontSize = 20"});

    console.log('print again');

    </script>
</body>
```

When I try to run this extension I get the error:
Error during tabs.executeScript: Unknown error.       extensions/extension process bindings.js:85

Does anyone have any idea what this could possibly be or how to fix it?  I get no error when I do not include the line chrome.tabs.executeScript, and I get the error no matter what I write for the parameters of chrome.tabs.executeScript. 
I also get the error when I include chrome.tabs.executeScript inside a function that is called whenever the browserAction is clicked

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You are injecting code into selected tab right when background page loads for the first time, which happens on `chrome://extensions` page where you cannot inject anything.

Not sure why you are still getting error inside browser action listener, maybe you have extensions page still opened?

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! it works when I close the extension page and put it in the function!